# Sending mail symfony2 not gmail

Tags: php, symfony, email, swiftmailer

I used to use gmail to send mails from my symfony2 app. But now google seems to block this service instead i get the following message to my gmail account when i try to send mail using SwiftMailer:

```
Someone just tried to sign in to your Google Account xxx@gmail.com from an app that doesn't meet modern security standards.

Details:
Saturday, November 7, 2015 9:26 PM (Central European Standard Time)
France*
We strongly recommend that you use a secure app, like Gmail, to access your account. All apps made by Google meet these security standards. Using a less secure app, on the other hand, could leave your account vulnerable. Learn more.

Google stopped this sign-in attempt, but you should review your recently used devices:
```

Now if not google what should i use to send mails ?

Note:  I need something free ofcourse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of mailing services like [Sendmail](http://www.sendmail.org), [Exim](http://www.exim.org/), and so on. Just install one and [configure your app accordingly](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html).